# Branch vs Tag.. Coming from SVN world

Tags: java, git, maven

I was working on a java, maven project using SVN.  we all work off the trunk and once the project is tested and ready to be release we make a release branch.

We are now moving to GIT, YAHOO... We all work on branches on the locals workstations then merNge them into the master and push them up for sharing so is just like working in SVN but now for the real issue at release time should we make a branch or a tag?

We would like to hear how other shops do this, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A branch allows you to concurrently develop multiple hotfixes/features while allowing your master branch to stay untouched. A tag is a label to a commit that you can use for further reference. They are both pointers to commits in history but unlike branches tags are static they are attached to one commit and will stay there.

Before releasing a new stable version you would tag the commit you released on. So what you need are tags.

Answer (score 3):

A tag allows remembering which commit was used to build a release. If you want to fix bugs after the release on a branch separated from the master branch, you can create a branch, directly or later, from this commit. Just like in Subversion.

Comment: A you are saying use tags for release spots and I can always make a branch from the tag at a later date.. Is this right

Comment: A tag is just that: a tag. A label on a commit. Just like in Subversion. A branch is just that: a branch. Something starting from another branch, and where you can store other commits. The notions are the same between git and subversion. The only difference is that a subversion tag is implemented as a branch, and doesn't prevent you from doing changes in this tag-implemented-as-branch. But you're not supposed to do that in Subversion.

Comment: Yes, you can always create a branch from an old commit (whether it's tagged or not). Just like in Subversion.

Comment: what do you use to MARK and release timeshot... a tag or a branch

Comment: To mark it, I label a commit with a tag. To release it, I use my preferred build tool, using the sources labeled by this tag. If I have to make changes before the release, specific to the release, I create a branch, make the changes, commit, create a tag, and release.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to have a release branch where everything is merged to for a release. When it's time for a new version to be released, everything gets merged into this branch, and a tag created for the version number.

This means you can always check out the release branch to get the latest released version and it's also easy to go back and view past releases.